# Finding Out Value of Multiple Dropdowns, Only Checks The First Options

Tags: javascript, html

Here Is My Code:

```
    <select id="gender" style="width: 125px;">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Other</option></select>

    <select id="car" style="width: 125px;">
    <option id="2">Select</option>
    <option id="2">Sport</option>
    <option id="2">Luxury</option>
    <option id="2">Muscle</option>
    <option id="2">Formula 1</option></select>
```

The Problem Is That When I Run:

```
    var gender = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[document.getElementById("gender").selectedIndex].value;
    var car = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[document.getElementById("car").selectedIndex].value;
```

It Understands That I Have Two Selects But Only Checks The First Options Of The First Select. So When I Select The First Option For Each I Get:

Female
Female

Instead Of Female and Sport.

Comment: I don't understand exactly... do you want the selected gender in the gender variable and the selected car in the car variable?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the selected option for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try directly like below

```
var gender=document.getElementById('gender').value;
var car=document.getElementById('car').value
```

It will give you the selected value only.